# Linking Mapinfo polygon to MS Access DBMS records?

Tags: mapinfo, ms-access

Does anyone know of simple way or bit of code to link a MS ACCESS DBMS point to an associated polygon, so that spatial attributes of the polygon can be recorded into the DBMS fields.

I am a user not a tech programmer.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the Update Column function in MapInfo Pro to do this.

- Table to Update: DBMS_Table
- Column to Update:
- Get Value From Table: Polygon_Table
- Calculate: Value
- of:

[image]

Click on the Join button to specify how to join the two tables.

Select the option "where object from table DBMS_table is within objects from table Polygon_Table".

[image]

Repeat this for each column you need to update.